# Assign SHIFT+Delete KeyGesture to DevExpress bar item WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, keyboard-shortcuts, devexpress

Cant assign SHIFT+Delete KeyGesture to DevExpress bar item in WPF. Is there any restriction on that or am i doing it wrongly?
 `<dxb:BarButtonItem

                    x:Name="btnDelete"

                    Command="{Binding BtnDelete_Command}"

                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=view}"

                    KeyGesture="SHIFT+Delete"

                    Content="Delete" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code I tried:

```
    <dxb:BarManager>
        <dxb:BarManager.Items>
            <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="btnDelete" Command="{Binding BtnDelete_Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=view}" KeyGesture="SHIFT+Delete" Content="Delete" />
        </dxb:BarManager.Items>
        <dxb:BarManager.Bars>
            <dxb:Bar>
                <dxb:Bar.ItemLinks>
                    <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="btnDelete"/>
                </dxb:Bar.ItemLinks>
            </dxb:Bar>
        </dxb:BarManager.Bars>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="sdgsdg" />
            <TextBox x:Name="view"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </dxb:BarManager>



public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public ICommand BtnDelete_Command { get; set; }
    public MainWindow() {
        BtnDelete_Command = new MyCommand();
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class MyCommand : ICommand {
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter) {
        MessageBox.Show(parameter.GetType().ToString());
    }
}
```

It works properly here.  If the editor is not focused, the command is executed.  If the editor is focused, it processed this key combination itself and thus command isn't executed.

Comment: Thank you for answer..It seems right. And how can i make that gesture work when textbox IS focused?(sorry, im new to wpf)